# vertical scrolling html webos application

Tags: javascript, html, webos

I have an application that is basically an html page. I have a problem, since the html page is longer than the visible screen and the page does not scroll

Someone can help me so that it can be scrolled using enyo or mojo that is not very difficult to use. Please

```
<div id="alertsIndex" class="row">
    <div id="Content-alerts" class="content-alerts" style="width:100%;"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A browser should make  a website with content higher than screen scrollable automatically?

Comment: Yes indeed, but as I develop the application in webOS IDE when I show it on my TV with the remote control it does not scroll.

Comment: I've the same issue. Remote control doesn't work to move around the app